# How to install fileBeat on M1 Mac

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew, kibana, filebeat

I have installed filebeat with homebrew on my mac which is m1 silicon, but I couldn't find the filebeat configuration file after the installation was successful. Please help me. Thank you.

```sh
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/services).
No changes to formulae.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/filebeat/manifests/8.1.2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/filebeat/blobs/sha256:f42947a0250332fca402f01cbfb52f957e4aae1958e7f6723617f
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:f42947a0250332fca402f01cbfb52f957e4aae1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring filebeat--8.1.2.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To restart filebeat after an upgrade:
  brew services restart filebeat
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/filebeat/bin/filebeat
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/filebeat/8.1.2: 216 files, 64.7MB
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in the last 30 days, running now...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Answer (score 1):

All right, the configuration is in /opt/homebrew/etc/filebeat

```sh
/opt/homebrew/etc/filebeat
```